# Messed up slider picture dimension

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I have built a website using Minamaze1.1.2 theme free addition.
While changing the CSS code I somehow changed the dimension of the slider pictures.
Now the left side isn’t proportional to the right.

You can see in the site address:
http://springlogy.com/

Tried restore option, but ended up only erasing the work I did!
How can I fix it??

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but for some reason, the UL container which represents your slider container has an added padding. Maybe try to overwrite it's class in css and make it padding:0. Should fix it

Comment: do you mean this one:#slider .rslides-container {
padding: 2px 10px; ? tried it, didnt work...

Answer (score 2):

On the element `#site-header #slider #slider-core .rslides-container .rslides-inner ul` which is the `ul` containing the slider `li` items, you must have removed the `padding: 0;` rule.

Add that into the CSS and that will fix it.

I think the rule for that element is on line 922 of your `style.css`. Open it up and ctrl+f for `#slider .rslides {`

Add `padding: 0;` into that CSS class and it should fix it nicely.

Comment: Do you mean one of this ul? <br/>

#slider .rslides-inner { <br/>
 position: relative; <br/>
 width: 960px; <br/>
 max-width: 100%; <br/>
 margin: 0 auto; <br/>
 border: 0; <br/>
 overflow: hidden; <br/>
} <br/>
#slider .rslides-inner li { <br/>
 height: auto; <br/>
 list-style: none; <br/>
} <br/>
#slider .rslides-container { <br/>
padding: 2px 10px; <br/>
 <br/>
tried to add it, didn’t  work ):

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you wanted your slider's text aligned to the center?

If so, altering

```
 <div id="slider">
```

to

```
<div id="slider" style="text-align:center;">
```

would do the trick.

*(please note. This could also have been placed in a css file, as shown below:)*

```
#slider{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Nop, I mean that the picture itself isn’t proportional to the right and to the left

Answer (score 0):

Your slider ul has 40px padding-left that is pushing it over.

Add

```
.rslides-inner .slides [
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following rule to line #922 of your css file will fix the problem.

`padding-left:0px`

The whole rule looks like this:

```
#slider .rslides {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Happy to help! Good luck with your project.